# WebForms application - 'The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.'

Tags: c#, webforms, iis-7

I have scoured the internet for this particular error and I've found similar ones but nothing that matched my problem. I have a WebForms application that continues to give me the error below.

`Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.`

It highlights the line: (I've replaced the username and password with generic text for this post.)

`<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="(Domain\(Username)" password="(Password)"/>`

Whenever I change impersonate="false" it just says that LocalHost cannot be found. I'm not sure what the issue is here and I can't seem to get the application to run locally.

Comment: This is not an error that you can fix with any code. Solving trust relationship issues for machines in domain may be on-topic on [sf] or [su], but unlikely here.

Comment: Ah that understands why I can't find any code that's wrong. I'll post over there.

Comment: You use a configuration setting that's too old. Stop using `<identity>` tag that way, and change IIS application pool identity instead.

Comment: This is an old WebForms application that broke. It's rather old. I did a pull from the Git repository to fix a bug in the program but when I tried compiling it it throws that error. It's currently running in production.